# How to insert results from select (from db1) into table (in db2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, connection-string

I have two databases with the same table. I have a connectionstring to connect to both databases.

How can I perform a `select from table A` in DB1 and insert the results in table `A` in DB2?

My connectionstrings:

- For DB1: `Server=12.34.56.789,12345;Database=shop;User Id=admin; Password=1234567890;`
- For DB2: `Server=34.12.56.789,12345;Database=shop;User Id=admin; Password=1234567890;`

Comment: I hope this is not your real password. Can you use linked servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

```
/*do this from target server*/
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='12.34.56.789,12345'
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin '12.34.56.789,12345', 'false', NULL, 'admin', '1234567890'

SELECT * INTO tableA 
FROM [12.34.56.789,12345].[shop].[dbo].[tableA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use linked server in sql server and then use Insert.. select syntax something like this:

```
Insert Into DB2.A 
Select * from DB1.A
```